# Sort ListView in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

How to sort array in NativeScript from earliest to latest?

My code :

```
import observableArray = require("data/observable-array");
var orderListRaw = new observableArray.ObservableArray([]);
var orderList = orderListRaw.sort((a:number, b:number) => {return a - b;});

      function news(args) {
      fetch('https://testapi.local/', {
        method: 'GET',
      }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(r) {
          var res = r.results;
          orderList.length = 0
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
          for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            var order = {
              createdAt: res[i].createdAt,
              title: res[i].title,
              desc: res[i].desc,
              image: res[i].image.url
            }
            orderList.push(order);
          }
        },
        function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        });
    };
```

The result is, my array still sort in earliest to latest.
Many thanks

Comment: so you want to sort the array by the order of `createdAt`, don't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use compare functions to sort ObsevableArray but you should use them after the array has some actual values pushed in and from there:

```
    orderList.sort(function (orderA, orderB) {
        var createdAtA = orderA.createdAt; // what is createdAt!? probably normilize it for comparision
        var createdAtB = orderB.createdAt;
        return (createdAtA < createdAtB ) ? -1 : (createdAtA > createdAtB ) ? 1 : 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var moment = require("moment");
orderList.sort((left: any, right: any) => {
    return moment(left.createdAt).isBefore(right.createdAt) ? -1 : 1;
});
```